# Cannot Adjust Brightness on Acer Aspire 5332

Tags: brightness, acer, aspire

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 with the Windows installer. It appears to be running fine, however the screen is extremely dull and I don't appear to be able to adjust the brightness... I entered the settings and tried to play with the brightness there, however there is no change in apparent brightness whether it is set to high or low on the menu.

I am using an Acer Aspire 5332 with Windows 7 Ultimate. It is worth noting that the original keyboard from the laptop no longer works, so I am using a USB keyboard (meaning that I don't have access to the Fn keys)...

It's also worth noting that in recovery mode the brightness seems fine, however the resolution is poor.

Another thing: I entered the following (that I found in a similar thread):

```
 sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00
```

This solves the issue, however I have to do it again after every restart, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Put your `setpci` command in `/etc/rc.local`.
See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1744809